# cte in postgresql vs ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, common-table-expression

my observation is we can not mix cte with recursive cte in a nested cte case in postgresql, but looks like we can do that in MS SQL. am I right? for example, for postgresql, I will get error in this case

```
with cte1 ( ... ),
recursive cte2 (...)
select * from cte1 join cte2;
```

but looks like it works for ms sql. is this correct?

Comment: Just put the `recursive` keyword before the first CTE.  It applies to the entire `with` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both databases support mixing non-recursive and recursive common table expressions.

In Postgres, the syntax is:

```
with recursive
    cte1 as (...), -- non-recursive CTE
    cte2 as (...)  -- recursive CTE
select * from cte1 join cte2
```

SQL Server does not recognizes the `recursive` keyword, so that's:

```
with 
    cte1 as (...), -- non-recursive CTE
    cte2 as (...)  -- recursive CTE
select * from cte1 join cte2
```